# How could i submit for "manage_pages" permission for the review, after app is migrated?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I didn't submit my app for login review(v2.0). My app got migrated automatically. How could i submit for "manage_pages" permission for the review?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just go through the review process as normal; so submit for review.

Currently there is a know issue for creating Pages with Test users (https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1379799389014320/). In your submission notes you can refer to this report and explain that you are not able to provide an example page. The review team can then test with their own accounts.